# Get all associated records given one match

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have two models with a one to many relation. Given that below query returns a record of ModelA (lets say it has id 1) with 3 associated ModelB (1, 2 and 3).

If I were to replace [1,2,3] in the query to just [1] it would still return the same ModelA record (with id 1) but only with the one associated ModelB (of id 1). How can I modify this query so it returns all three associated ModelB records?

```
ModelA.findAll({
  include: [{
    model: JoinTableModel,
    where: {
      modelB_ID: {
        [Op.in]: [1,2,3]
      }
    },
    include: [ModelB]
  }]
})
```

Model definitions like so.

```
db.ModelA.hasMany(db.JoinTableModel, { foreignKey: 'modelA_ID' })
db.JoinTableModel.belongsTo(db.ModelA, { foreignKey: 'modelA_ID' })

db.ModelB.hasMany(db.JoinTableModel, { foreignKey: 'modelB_ID' })
db.JoinTableModel.belongsTo(db.ModelB, { foreignKey: 'modelB_ID' })
```

Comment: Show all three model definitions and their association definitions

Comment: @Anatoly Updated question with model definitions

Comment: At least you should move `include: [ModelB]` to one line higher inside `include` of JoinTableModel

Comment: @Anatoly Oh, I missed some brackets when i posted it here, its edited.

Comment: Ok. So you have one ModelA with id=1 and three ModelB with ids 1,2,3 and three records in JoinTableModel 1,1 1,2 and 1,3. Right? So what are you trying to achieve? Do you wish to get all ModelB that are linked with a certain ModelA that has a link with a given ModelB (for instance ModelB = 1)?

Comment: @Anatoly Yes, exactly!

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
JoinTableModel.findAll({
  where: {
    modelB_ID: {
      [Op.in]: [1]
    }
  },
  include: [{
    model: ModelA,
    include: [{
      model: JoinTableModel,
      include: [ModelB]
    }]
  }]
})
```

If you add an association like this:

```
ModelA.belongsToMany(ModelB, { through: JoinTableModel })
```

then you can simplify the above query to this one:

```
JoinTableModel.findAll({
  where: {
    modelB_ID: {
      [Op.in]: [1]
    }
  },
  include: [{
    model: ModelA,
    include: [ModelB]
  }]
})
```

Comment: Will try this. Allthough my initial query is a little more complex than what  I posted (for example it includes one more association thats very similar to ModelB). I will see if I can take this and tweak it to make it work for my use case, very useful either way, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone with a similar issue as me, what I ended up doing that works for my case is modifying my initial query like this.

```
ModelA.findAll({
  where: {
    id: sequelize.literal(`
      ModelA.id 
      IN (
        SELECT modelA_ID FROM JoinTableModel
        WHERE modelB_ID IN (1,2,3)
        GROUP BY modelA_ID
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 3
      )`)
  },
  include: [{
    model: JoinTableModel,
    include: [ModelB]
  }]
})
```

This way I could easily replace `IN (1,2,3)` and `COUNT(*) 3` with `IN (1)` and `COUNT(*) 1` and it would still work as intended and it doesn't break any other part of the query.

I'm still curious if anyone could solve this without using `sequelize.literal` in any way or if there is a more efficient way of doing it.